# what is the difference between NOT EXIST and NOT IN?

Tags: mysql, sql

specifically
how I would pick which to use when dealing with NULL values?

Comment: We need way more details.  What is NULL?   Do you want NULL or dont want null?  You can just use where fieldname is NULL or fieldname is not null

Comment: You pretty much always want the semantics of `NOT EXISTS` when it comes to `NULL`. I don't think I've ever wanted the `NOT IN` semantics here

Answer (score 1):

You should always use `not exists` with subqueries.  It handles `NULL` values in an intuitive way.

If you have:

```
where t.id not in (select x.id from x)
```

And `x.id` is *ever* `NULL`, then *no rows* are returned at all.  This is because of the definition of `NULL` values.

The equivalent formulation:

```
where not exists (select 1 from x where x.id = t.id)
```

behaves as you would expect.

Another advantage of `not exists` is that you can handle multiple columns at once:

```
where not exists (select 1 from x where x.id = t.id and x.date = t.date)
```

Some databases support tuples, which allows you to express this as `not in`, but not all do.

Comment: one other difference is that If `t.id` is `NULL` then the `NOT EXISTS` will include it. The `not in` won't include it unless `select x.id from x` returns an empty set